# processing, sound overlapping

Tags: audio, processing, overlapping, minimum

I have some problems to understand how to play some tracks 
one after the other avoiding the overlap effect. 
I am using the Minim library but I did not find a way 
to detect the final moment of the first sound to start the second one.
Can anybody give me my some tips?
this is my sketch

```
import ddf.minim.*;
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player[]=new AudioPlayer[4];
String filenames[] = new String[]{"sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3"};

void setup(){
 minim = new Minim(this);
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
   player[i] = minim.loadFile(filenames[i]);
   player[i].play();
   print(filenames);
 }
}

void draw(){}

void stop(){
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
   player[i].close();
 }
 minim.stop();
 super.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can poll player[i].isPlaying() to see if the sound is still playing before starting the next one.  In your code, this means keeping track of which player is currently active, and moving the call to the .play() method into draw().